# Add shell script parameters to java application

Tags: java

I have a shell script `test.sh` like this :

```
echo hello enter your password and username
read user
read password
echo username $user and $password
```

Now I want to implement this in a java application, which will execute this shell skript automatically and with "sh test.sh"

I do this in java eclipse on a Windows machine after that I want to export this application into a jar file and want to execute it on a Linux server.

I started with something like this

```
String [] cmd = {"sh test.sh", "user" , "password"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); ...
```

For adding the parameters to the command, but I think it's not the right way to do that.

Comment: Can you edit the test.sh script? it is its not very clear. Then- do you want to export environment variables using the scripts, and read those variables from the java program?

Comment: Test.sh is edited

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your shell script tries to read `$username` and `$password` from an input stream. However, from Java you are passing your arguments as script arguments.

The execution from Java will work if you change your script to:

```sh
echo hello enter your password and username
echo username $1 and $2
```

If you need to pass arguments to a script that reads from an input stream, you need to use the `ProcessBuilder` Java class.

Comment: thank u so much for your answer. The shell script test.sh sould be executed and for password and username I want to give a fix one. Means it's always "user1" and password "pwd" (just for testing) that means I need the process builder ?

Comment: If you are fine with using script arguments, you can just change your script according to my suggestion i.e. access arguments via `$1`,`$2`,... instead of the `read` statements. If you need to read in the username and password via the `read` statements, then you would indeed have to use the `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: If this comment helped you, please consider upvoting or accepting as the correct answer.

Comment: the input for the user name and the password I want to do with the parameters. It is always the same . But I really don't know how to do ist with the process builder ..